# SSSD ad authentication windows server 2012 R2

Tags: samba, pam, active-directory, kerberos

I want to login with AD users on a client with no gui. It is a Ubuntu 16.04 machine with SSSD. Active Directory server is Windows Server 2012 R2. I cannot login on console login with "aduser@srv.local" or "aduser\srv.local" neither "su aduser" works however I can kinit and successfully get a ticket and adding the machine to the domain also works.

I followed this tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/sssd-ad.html

I'm not sure if PAM is configured correctly or that ticket is not created at boot time or that keytabs are correct.

The SSSD version is: 1.13.4-1ubuntu1.1
The version of libpam-modules is: 1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2

## What I have did:

```
root@srv2:~# sudo kinit Administrator
Password for Administrator@SRV.LOCAL:
root@srv2:~# sudo klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: Administrator@SRV.LOCAL

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
12/29/2016 07:27:28  12/29/2016 17:27:28  krbtgt/SRV.LOCAL@SRV.LOCAL
        renew until 01/05/2017 07:27:27
```

Join domain:

```
root@srv2:~# net ads join -k
Using short domain name -- SRV
Joined 'SRV2' to dns domain 'srv.local'
```

After configuration and join to domain I rebooted the computer I created a test user in active directory named linux. I tried su linux to change to that user but it hasn't been added in the passwd

Getent passwd:

```
root@srv2:~# getent passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/nologin
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-timesync:x:100:102:systemd Time Synchronization,,,:/run/systemd:/bin/false
systemd-network:x:101:103:systemd Network Management,,,:/run/systemd/netif:/bin/false
systemd-resolve:x:102:104:systemd Resolver,,,:/run/systemd/resolve:/bin/false
systemd-bus-proxy:x:103:105:systemd Bus Proxy,,,:/run/systemd:/bin/false
syslog:x:104:108::/home/syslog:/bin/false
_apt:x:105:65534::/nonexistent:/bin/false
lxd:x:106:65534::/var/lib/lxd/:/bin/false
messagebus:x:107:111::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
uuidd:x:108:112::/run/uuidd:/bin/false
dnsmasq:x:109:65534:dnsmasq,,,:/var/lib/misc:/bin/false
sshd:x:110:65534::/var/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
mark:x:1000:1000:mark,,,:/home/mark:/bin/bash
ntp:x:111:117::/home/ntp:/bin/false
sssd:x:112:118:SSSD system user,,,:/var/lib/sss:/bin/false
```

wbinfo query information:

```
root@srv2:~# wbinfo -t
checking the trust secret for domain SRV via RPC calls succeeded
```

wbinfo -u -g:

```
root@srv2:~# wbinfo -u -g
SRV\administrator
SRV\guest
SRV\krbtgt
SRV\mark
SRV\test1
SRV\linux
SRV\winrmremotewmiusers__
SRV\domain computers
SRV\domain controllers
SRV\schema admins
SRV\enterprise admins
SRV\cert publishers
SRV\domain admins
SRV\domain users
SRV\domain guests
SRV\group policy creator owners
SRV\ras and ias servers
SRV\allowed rodc password replication group
SRV\denied rodc password replication group
SRV\read-only domain controllers
SRV\enterprise read-only domain controllers
SRV\cloneable domain controllers
SRV\protected users
SRV\dnsadmins
SRV\dnsupdateproxy
SRV\dhcp users
SRV\dhcp administrators
```

ldapsearch with GSSAPI shows error with keytabs:

```
root@srv2:~# /usr/bin/ldapsearch -H ldap://srv.local -Y GSSAPI -N -b "dc=src,dc=local" "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=ad
user))"
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Local error (-2)
        additional info: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (No Kerberos credentials available)
```

/var/log/sssd/ldap_child.log:

```
(Thu Dec 29 07:27:40 2016) [[sssd[ldap_child[33841]]]] [ldap_child_get_tgt_sync] (0x0010): Failed to init credentials: Preauthe
ntication fail
```

/var/log/auth.log:

```
Dec 29 20:03:59 srv2 login[1344]: pam_unix(login:auth): check pass; user unknown
Dec 29 20:03:59 srv2 login[1344]: pam_unix(login:auth): authentication failure; logname=LOGIN uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser$Dec 29 20:04:24 srv2 sssd_be: GSSAPI client step 1
Dec 29 20:04:24 srv2 sssd_be: GSSAPI client step 1
Dec 29 20:04:24 srv2 sssd_be: GSSAPI client step 1
Dec 29 20:04:24 srv2 sssd_be: GSSAPI client step 1
```

I used tcpdump to filter ldap, dns and krb5 ports. The capture can be viewed here: http://www.filedropper.com/ldap-sssd

Errors that occurred are:

```
67  0.112875    192.168.253.200 192.168.253.100 DNS 151 Standard query response 0xe2ee No such name SRV _kerberos-master._tcp.SRV.LOCAL SOA dc1.srv.local
```

I have read that the error below can safely be ignored:

```
31  0.094884    192.168.253.200 192.168.253.100 KRB5    231 KRB Error: KRB5KDC_ERR_PREAUTH_REQUIRED
```

## Configuration files:

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.253.100 srv2.srv.local srv2

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
#::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
#ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
#ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 192.168.253.200
search srv.local
```

/etc/krb5.conf:

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = SRV.LOCAL
    renew_lifetime = 7d
    ticket_lifetime = 24h
    dns_lookup_realm = true
    dns_lookup_kdc = true

# The following krb5.conf variables are only for MIT Kerberos.
    krb4_config = /etc/krb.conf
    krb4_realms = /etc/krb.realms
    kdc_timesync = 1
    ccache_type = 4
    forwardable = true
    proxiable = true
    rdns = false

# The following encryption type specification will be used by MIT Kerberos
# if uncommented.  In general, the defaults in the MIT Kerberos code are
# correct and overriding these specifications only serves to disable new
# encryption types as they are added, creating interoperability problems.
#
# Thie only time when you might need to uncomment these lines and change
# the enctypes is if you have local software that will break on ticket
# caches containing ticket encryption types it doesn't know about (such as
# old versions of Sun Java).

#   default_tgs_enctypes = des3-hmac-sha1
#   default_tkt_enctypes = des3-hmac-sha1
#   permitted_enctypes = des3-hmac-sha1

# The following libdefaults parameters are only for Heimdal Kerberos.
    v4_instance_resolve = false
    v4_name_convert = {
        host = {
            rcmd = host
            ftp = ftp
        }
        plain = {
            something = something-else
        }
    }
    fcc-mit-ticketflags = true

[realms]
    SRV.LOCAL = {
        kdc = srv.local
        admin_server = srv.local
        default_domain = srv.local
    }
    ATHENA.MIT.EDU = {
        kdc = kerberos.mit.edu:88
        kdc = kerberos-1.mit.edu:88
        kdc = kerberos-2.mit.edu:88
        admin_server = kerberos.mit.edu
        default_domain = mit.edu
    }
    MEDIA-LAB.MIT.EDU = {
        kdc = kerberos.media.mit.edu
        admin_server = kerberos.media.mit.edu
    }
    ZONE.MIT.EDU = {
        kdc = casio.mit.edu
        kdc = seiko.mit.edu
        admin_server = casio.mit.edu
    }
    MOOF.MIT.EDU = {
        kdc = three-headed-dogcow.mit.edu:88
        kdc = three-headed-dogcow-1.mit.edu:88
        admin_server = three-headed-dogcow.mit.edu
    }
    CSAIL.MIT.EDU = {
        kdc = kerberos-1.csail.mit.edu
        kdc = kerberos-2.csail.mit.edu
        admin_server = kerberos.csail.mit.edu
        default_domain = csail.mit.edu
        krb524_server = krb524.csail.mit.edu
    }
    IHTFP.ORG = {
        kdc = kerberos.ihtfp.org
        admin_server = kerberos.ihtfp.org
    }
    GNU.ORG = {
        kdc = kerberos.gnu.org
        kdc = kerberos-2.gnu.org
        kdc = kerberos-3.gnu.org
        admin_server = kerberos.gnu.org
    }
    1TS.ORG = {
        kdc = kerberos.1ts.org
        admin_server = kerberos.1ts.org
    }
    GRATUITOUS.ORG = {
        kdc = kerberos.gratuitous.org
        admin_server = kerberos.gratuitous.org
    }
    DOOMCOM.ORG = {
        kdc = kerberos.doomcom.org
        admin_server = kerberos.doomcom.org
    }
    ANDREW.CMU.EDU = {
        kdc = kerberos.andrew.cmu.edu
        kdc = kerberos2.andrew.cmu.edu
        kdc = kerberos3.andrew.cmu.edu
        admin_server = kerberos.andrew.cmu.edu
        default_domain = andrew.cmu.edu
    }
    CS.CMU.EDU = {
        kdc = kerberos.cs.cmu.edu
        kdc = kerberos-2.srv.cs.cmu.edu
        admin_server = kerberos.cs.cmu.edu
    }
    DEMENTIA.ORG = {
        kdc = kerberos.dementix.org
        kdc = kerberos2.dementix.org
        admin_server = kerberos.dementix.org
    }
    stanford.edu = {
        kdc = krb5auth1.stanford.edu
        kdc = krb5auth2.stanford.edu
        kdc = krb5auth3.stanford.edu
        master_kdc = krb5auth1.stanford.edu
        admin_server = krb5-admin.stanford.edu
        default_domain = stanford.edu
    }
        UTORONTO.CA = {
                kdc = kerberos1.utoronto.ca
                kdc = kerberos2.utoronto.ca
                kdc = kerberos3.utoronto.ca
                admin_server = kerberos1.utoronto.ca
                default_domain = utoronto.ca
    }

[domain_realm]
    .srv.local = dc1.srv.local
    srv.local = dc1.srv.local
    .mit.edu = ATHENA.MIT.EDU
    mit.edu = ATHENA.MIT.EDU
    .media.mit.edu = MEDIA-LAB.MIT.EDU
    media.mit.edu = MEDIA-LAB.MIT.EDU
    .csail.mit.edu = CSAIL.MIT.EDU
    csail.mit.edu = CSAIL.MIT.EDU
    .whoi.edu = ATHENA.MIT.EDU
    whoi.edu = ATHENA.MIT.EDU
    .stanford.edu = stanford.edu
    .slac.stanford.edu = SLAC.STANFORD.EDU
        .toronto.edu = UTORONTO.CA
        .utoronto.ca = UTORONTO.CA

[login]
    krb4_convert = true
    krb4_get_tickets = false

[logging]
    default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
```

permissions sssd.conf

```
drw-------  2 root root 4096 Dec 29 08:37 . 
drwxr-xr-x 96 root root 4096 Dec 29 08:34 ..
-rw-------  1 root root  696 Dec 29 08:30 sssd.conf
```

/etc/sssd/sssd.conf:

```
[sssd]
services = nss, pam
config_file_version = 2
domains = SRV.LOCAL
#default_domain_suffix = SRV.LOCAL

[domain/SRV.LOCAL]
id_provider = ad
access_provider = ad

# Use this if users are being logged in at /.
# This example specifies /home/DOMAIN-FQDN/user as $HOME.  Use with pam_mkhomedir.so
override_homedir = /home/%d/%u

# Uncomment if the client machine hostname doesn't match the computer object on the DC.
# ad_hostname = srv2.srv.local

# Uncomment if DNS SRV resolution is not working
# ad_server = dc1.srv.local

# Uncomment if the AD domain is named differently than the Samba domain
# ad_domain = SRV.LOCAL

# Enumeration is discouraged for performance reasons.
# enumerate = true
```

/etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
[global]

workgroup = SRV
client signing = yes
client use spnego = yes
kerberos method = secrets and keytab
realm = SRV.LOCAL
security = ads
```

/etc/nsswitch.conf:

```
passwd:         compat sss
shadow:         compat
group:          compat sss
gshadow:        files
hosts:          files dns

bootparams:     files

ethers:         files
netmasks:       files
networks:       files
protocols:      files
rpc:            files
services:       files sss

netgroup:       nis sss

publickey:      files

automount:      files
aliases:        files
sudoers:        files sss
```

/etc/pam.d/common-auth

```
    #
    # /etc/pam.d/common-auth - authentication settings common to all services
    #
    # This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
    # and should contain a list of the authentication modules that define
    # the central authentication scheme for use on the system
    # (e.g., /etc/shadow, LDAP, Kerberos, etc.).  The default is to use the
    # traditional Unix authentication mechanisms.
    #
    # As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
    # To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
    # local modules either before or after the default block, and use
    # pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
    # pam-auth-update(8) for details.

    # here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
    auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
    auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_sss.so use_first_pass
    # here's the fallback if no module succeeds
    auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
    # prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
    # this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
    # since the modules above will each just jump around
    auth    required                        pam_permit.so
    # and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
    # end of pam-auth-update config
```

/etc/pam.d/common-password

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/common-password - password-related modules common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of modules that define the services to be
# used to change user passwords.  The default is pam_unix.

# Explanation of pam_unix options:
#
# The "sha512" option enables salted SHA512 passwords.  Without this option,
# the default is Unix crypt.  Prior releases used the option "md5".
#
# The "obscure" option replaces the old `OBSCURE_CHECKS_ENAB' option in
# login.defs.
#
# See the pam_unix manpage for other options.

# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
password    requisite           pam_pwquality.so retry=3
password    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512
password    sufficient          pam_sss.so use_authtok
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
password    requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
password    required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

Comment: I know it's a very old question, but I'm convinced the issue is shown in your `auth.log`, and I'm having the same problem. I have numerous Linux boxen authenticating with AD via SSSD, and they show an initial failure to authenticate using `pam_unix`, followed by success using `pam_sss`. So, why didn't yours (and one of mine), appear to even try `pam_sss`?

Comment: btw, `getent passwd` showed exactly what it should (`# enumerate = true` at the end of `sssd.conf`). `getent passwd aduser` should have worked, and does on my system.